# Plot binned discrete data with spaces between bars in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have integer data whose frequency I want to plot within numerically ranged bins. I can plot a histogram, but the plot puts the bars together like continuous data. I want spaces between the bars in order to reflect that the data are discrete. I've tried various approaches to make that happen and they don't quite make it.

It seems to me that this should happen out-of-the-box and I feel I must be missing something fundamental, like I'm using the wrong `geom` or I don't know a parameter I
need.

Here are some data and my first plot attempt. A histogram bins the data but it looks continuous.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

home_runs_df <- data.frame(home_runs = c(48, 40, 38, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 36, 36,
               35, 34, 34, 34, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33,
               33, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 31, 31, 29, 29,
               29, 29, 28, 28, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 26))

# Histogram bins, but plots like continuous.
home_runs_df %>%
    ggplot(mapping = aes(x = home_runs)) +
    geom_histogram(bins = 6)
```

I tried to set the bar width, but it's deprecated and the message suggests using `geom_bar()`, even though that's what I used! I suppose `stat = "bin"` ends up calling `geom_histogram()` under the hood instead of `geom_bar()`.

```
home_runs_df %>%
    ggplot(mapping = aes(x = home_runs)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "bin", bins = 6, width = 0.5)
```

This lets me change the width but how do I bin the data?

```
home_runs_df %>%
    ggplot(mapping = aes(x = home_runs)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "count", width = 0.75)
```

I can bin the data myself, but I resent having to. I expect `ggplot` to do that for me, and these results aren't completely what I want anyway.

- I'm missing the zero-height bin (41, 45].
- On the other hand, I do like where the x-axis labels appear, and I know how to set the text I want.

```
home_runs_df %>%
    mutate(bin = cut(home_runs, breaks = c(seq(25, 48, by = 4), Inf))) %>%
    ggplot(mapping = aes(x = bin)) +
    geom_histogram(stat = "count")
```

I got this approach from the `ggplot` reference documentation. Use `geom_bar()` and `scale_x_binned()`.

- The bars look the way I want for discrete data (spaces between).
- I don't like the way the tick marks display between the bins, as if the data are continuous.

```
home_runs_df %>%
    ggplot(aes(home_runs)) +
    geom_bar() +
    scale_x_binned(n.breaks = 6)
```

I bet there are tricky ways to displace the labels to the position I want. Is this degree of customization necessary? I think what I'm trying to do is pretty conventional. What am I missing?

### What I want is:

- Bin discrete, whole-number data.
- Plot the frequencies in the bins.
- Treat the integer data as discrete instead of continuous, with spaces between the bars and labels directly under each group.

Comment: You could try with `cut_interval`, i.e. `home_runs_df %>% ggplot(mapping = aes(x = cut_interval(home_runs, 6))) + geom_bar()`.

Comment: @stefan, this is exactly what I missed. The vignette for the `cut` functions says it all: "Discretise numeric data into categorical." I opted for `cut_width()`. If you make this into an Answer, I'll mark it as the one accepted. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the description of what you want to achieve I think that using `geom_bar` and binning with `ggplot2::cut_interval` or `ggplot2::cut_width` would be the way to go to have bars with padding and a discrete scale at the same time.

Note: I also added a `scale_x_discrete(drop = FALSE)` in case you want to show the intervals with no obs. too.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(home_runs_df, aes(x = cut_interval(home_runs, 6))) + 
  geom_bar() +
  scale_x_discrete(drop = FALSE)
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(home_runs_df, aes(x = cut_width(home_runs, 4, boundary = 26))) + 
  geom_bar() +
  scale_x_discrete(drop = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: You taught me a lot @stefan. Discretizing my data, and not dropping the empty bin, too. Fabulous. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use your `cut` tricks, but setting properly the `labels` argument in the `cut` function:

```
width <- 4
cutseq <- seq(25, 48, width)
home_runs_df %>%
  mutate(bin = cut(home_runs, 
                   breaks = c(cutseq, Inf),
                   labels = cutseq+width/2) %>%
           as.character()%>%
           as.numeric()) %>%
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = bin)) +
  geom_histogram(stat = "count",width = 3)
```

[image]

Therefore, each column is centered on the bin you choose, and you use continuous scale, that you can rescale as you want with `scale_x_continuous` if you need

Comment: This is a fine answer which I appreciate, @denis.